# On Broadcast Receiver can I open an activity

Tags: android, usb

public class USB extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
 private static final String TAG = "DetactUSB";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED"))
        {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);

                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB connected……….");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
                Log.i(TAG,"USB connected..");

        }
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED"))
        {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB Disconnected……….");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
        }
    }
```

Can I open an activity when USB is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start activity from receiver like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, activitytobelaunch.class);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: Thanks Vineet @  after Toast Message "USB Connected" I have written but there is an error on Start Activity.Bcoz I am not extends Activity class

Comment: Only just want to open My activity after toast message.

Comment: what do you mean by "I am not extends Activity class "?

Comment: yaa means In my Code I am not extends the Activity

Comment: my Activity is a different class.where I extends Activity.I want to open this Activity class after toast Message.Means After USB Connected

Comment: use above code which ever activity you want to start and from any where you want to start..

Comment: but I want to start activity class after toast message.bcoz I m not extending Activity so It is not accept  StartActivity(Intent)

Comment: there is an error for using this please see my above code and reply

Comment: what error are you getting? what activity class ? You can start activity with this code...can you show the class which you want to open but without activity you can not do that...

Comment: No my problem is solved.Thanks Vineet to a very great help..thankyou so much